# If I kept or if I keep

Tags: grammar

I want to know the difference between the two sentences and which one is right.

- If I kept saying I love you for the rest of my life it wouldn't be enough.
- If I keep saying I love you for the rest of my life it won't be enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: @tchrist Undoubtedly a duplicate but undoubtedly not a duplicate of that - at all or in any way. One of the many reasons why that question is not answerable by a diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. To me the differences are subtle and perhaps not meaningful because the endpoints are identical. The first looks ahead to a point just before death as though the action had been performed as envisioned, while the second is more in the moment, perhaps deciding whether to continue with the action. In either case, the sentiment is powerful.

Comment: Powerful, or banal.

Comment: Ahh, I see you are a romantic, @deadrat. :) As I grow older and contemplate centuries of civilization and over 7 billion people on the planet at present, I look less for originality and more for clarity of expression. (And continue to strive for the latter in my own work.)

Comment: Romantic?  Me?  When Charlie Manson finally gets stabbed to death in prison over a fine point of theology, I'll be the least romantic person in the western hemisphere.  Upvote for flattery, though.